# display xml feed asp.net C#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

This is my xml file:
http://goalserve.com/samples/soccer_inplay.xml

and this is my model:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "localteam")]
public class Localteam
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "goals")]
    public string Goals { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

this is my controller:

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

List<Localteam> s = new List<Localteam>();

doc.Load(Server.MapPath("soccer_inplay.xml"));

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/scores/category/"))
{
    s.Add(new Localteam
    {
        Name = node["Name"].InnerText          
    });
}

return View(s);
```

this is my view:

```
<table>

    <tr>

        <th>Name</th>

        <th>Goals</th>

    </tr>

    @foreach (WebApplication22.Models.Localteam s in Model)

    {
        <tr>

            <td>@s.Name</td>

            <td>@s.Goals</td>

        </tr>

    }

</table>
```

I want to display this  xml feed but I can't, I have problems with the view

Comment: i have it ,that's not the problem.

Comment: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\jt\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication22\WebApplication22\xml\soccer_inplay.xml'.  this is my error.

Comment: but soccer_inplay.xml is inside my solution

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;



namespace ConsoleApplication57
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "http://goalserve.com/samples/soccer_inplay.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);

            Localteam.teams = doc.Descendants("odd").Select(x => new Localteam()
            {
                Name = (string)x.Attribute("name"),
                games = x.Elements("type").Where(y => y.Attribute("id") != null).Select(y => new Game() {
                    id = (long)y.Attribute("id"),
                    opponent = (string)y.Attribute("name"),
                    suspend = (int)y.Attribute("suspend"),
                    odd = (Single)y.Attribute("odd"),
                    _type = (string)y.Attribute("type")
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }

    }
    public class Localteam
    {
        public static List<Localteam> teams = new List<Localteam>();

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Game> games { get; set; }
    }
    public class Game
    {
        public string opponent { get; set; }
        public long id { get; set; }
        public int suspend { get; set; }
        public Single odd { get; set; }
        public string _type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: i Cannot display it

Comment: The view must be consistent with the classes.  Names don't align.  Do you want a single table with both local team and opponent on each line or a separate table for each local team?  View looks like a single table but classes look like a different table for each local team.

Comment: Fix the view so it matches the xml results.